# ModelState serialization

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement custom validation in Web API. The code in Galloway's video on the subject seems to have changed. I did download the code and the way the create action filter is like this:

```
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

When I post to my api with bad data, this is what is returned:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"user":["First name cannot start with A"]}}
```

Notice how ModelState is not showing individual field causing the error (like user.FirstName).

When I run their application, ModelState does have the field info (comment.Author):

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"comment.Author":["Author is too long! This was validated on the server."]}}
```

I have the same action filter and very similar post web api. Why is my error not showing the field level detail?

Comment: Can someone verify if this is the way latest version of Web API library serializes the ModelState?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a known issue and has been fixed recently:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/362

Answer (score 0):

You probably did set your `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to be 'never' or did set the `customErrors` in Web.config file to be something else. See this post for details: http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/08/aspnet-web-api-error-detail-policy-now.html

Comment: I don't have customErrors and didn't see that variable being set in mine or theirs.